# Symfony: "Template "bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig" cannot be used as a trait"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I'm attempting to use [Symfony's Bootstrap 3 form theme](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme) file, including it as follows:

```
# config.yml
twig:
    form_themes:
        - 'WOSECoreBundle:Form:WOSE_form_theme.html.twig'
```

`WOSE_form_theme.html.twig` looks like this:

```
{% use "bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig" %}

{% block button_widget -%}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('btn-primary') ~ ' btn')|trim}) %}
    {{- parent() -}}
{%- endblock %}
```

However, whenever I browse to a page in my application which uses forms, I see the following error:

```
"Template "bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig" cannot be used as a trait"
```

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across [a similar issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1182#issuecomment-1274409) on Symfony's github account, which included the revealing remark, "A template is not traitable if it extends another one."

"Traits" in Twig are horizontal re-use, using the [`use` tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/use.html) - which we're doing in `WOSE_form_theme.html.twig` in this line: `{% use "bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig" %}`.

[Prior to Symfony 2.6.5](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/4509d36991bad58a5ceddc64c151c09ca622769d), Symfony's Bootstrap3 template included the following line:

```
{% extends "form_div_layout.html.twig" %}
```

This template `extends` another one, hence it cannot be referenced via `use` (it "is not traitable"), which we were trying to do.  In Symfony 2.6.5 and later, the Bootstrap template instead includes this line:

```
{% use "form_div_layout.html.twig" %}
```

**This >=2.6.5 version of the template no longer extends another one, and so can be safely referenced via `use` as we needed.**

Upgrading my project from Symfony 2.6.3 to 2.6.5 therefore solved this problem!